# BITS Upload Error in IIS 7 Win 2008 R2 SP 2

Tags: iis

In Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager; When I attempt to "Allow clients to upload files" (Default website -> Bits Uploads), I get the following error:

> An error occurred while enabling BITS uploads. Please check the event
>   log for more details about the exception. Exception Message: External
>   component has thrown an exception

Am doing this for my SCCM 2012 server installation. So far I haven't got any help from the other forums!

Comment: Umm... so, *did* you check the eventlog for more details about the exception?

Comment: I did but it does no shows anything significant. Attempting the above discussed problem does not trgger any event.

Comment: Furthermore the only ERROR in the eventlog with the keyword BITS is this one ... "Enabling BITS uploads for the virtual directory %2 failed with error %1. The error occurred while creating the cleanup task." And I have followed this resource for it http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408492(v=ws.10).aspx but still to no avail! The problem persists.